# Ember Data pluralizing url endpoints when using store.find

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I got an error with

`GET http://localhost:63342/people 404 (Not Found)`

and

`Assertion failed: Error while loading route:....`

Why does this error `http://localhost:63342/people 404` appears? I don't have this route.
here is my js code:

```
window.Models = Ember.Application.create();

Models.Router.map(function () {
    //匹配路由后显示person_list模板
    this.resource('persons', { path: '/' });
});

Models.PersonsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return this.store.find('person');
    },
    setupController:function(controller, model){
        controller.set('content', model)
    }
});


Models.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description:DS.attr('string')
});

Models.Person.FEATURES = [{
    name:'Kratos Zhang',
    description:'a c# coder in 7agree.'
}]
```

**and template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="persons">
<ul>
    {{#each item in persons}}
    <li>
        <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

why isn't it working?

Comment: You have a model called Person and the plural for this Model is going to be People (It's a convention), So, that is the reason that the model is trying to get something on people url.

If you want to modify the plural of you model you need to create a custom adapter and tell to ember that you want to use persons instead of people.

Probably this link helps you: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/specifying-pluralization-of-models/1447

Comment: Actually the plural of person is people. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can override pathForType in the adapter if that isn't your endpoint, Ember Data by default pluralizes endpoints

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
     //return Ember.String.pluralize(type);
     return type;
  },

});
```

This isn't necessary, you can delete it

```
setupController:function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model)
}
```

persons doesn't exist in the template

```
{{#each item in model}} 
  <li>
    <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
    <p>{{item.description}}</p>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  <li>
    <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
    <p>{{item.description}}</p>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: You can also create per-type adapters if you don't want to do this for everything in your app.